# Modal does not open: TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to display a pop up that I tried to implement as modal, but I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

I created the pop up as component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import User from '../types/user'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './chat-user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-user-profile.component.css']
})
export class ChatUserProfileComponent {

  me: User;

  ngOnInit() {}


  @ViewChild('ChatUserProfile') modal: ElementRef;

  open() {
    this.modal.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
  }

  close() {
    this.modal.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```html
<div #myChatUserProfile class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Some content here...</p>

      <div class="text-center mb-2">
        <h4><span class="badge badge-pill">{{me?.username}}</span></h4>
      </div>
    <!-- <button (click)="save()">Save</button> -->
    <button (click)="close()">Close</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Now I try to open it on clicking a button

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})

export class NavComponent {
  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(private amplifyService: AmplifyService, public router: Router) {
    this.amplifyService.authStateChange$.subscribe(authState => {
      const isLoggedIn = authState.state === 'signedIn' || authState.state === 'confirmSignIn';
      if (this.isLoggedIn && !isLoggedIn) {
        router.navigate(['']);
      } else if (!this.isLoggedIn && isLoggedIn) {
        router.navigate(['/chat']);
      }
      this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    });
  }

  public signOut() {
    this.amplifyService.auth().signOut();
  }
//Stuff for Profile Button
  @ViewChild('app-modal') modal: ChatUserProfileComponent
    openModal() {
    this.modal.open();
 }

}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-white" routerLink='/'>
    <img src="../../assets/img/chat.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="http://freepngimg.com/png/11489-chat-free-download-png">
    <strong>ChatQL</strong>
  </a>
   <!--STUFF TO INTEGRATE THE POP UP-->

  <app-modal #modal></app-modal>
  <button (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>

  <!------------->
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="nav-item">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="signOut()">Sign Out <i class="ion-log-in" data-pack="default" data-tags="sign in"></i></button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I also tried adding the modal to the constructor but that gave me a No Provider error.

I am based on the chatQL project and using [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-html-css-ertmj3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) as template for the pop up. I think something is wrong when initializing but I can not figure out where exactly.

Comment: Try @ViewChild(ChatUserProfileComponent) instead of  @ViewChild('app-modal')

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code, you have used template reference **#modal**

```
<app-modal #modal></app-modal>
```

So in typescript file you have to replace **'@ViewChild('app-modal')'** with **'@ViewChild('modal')'** like below

```
@ViewChild('modal') modal: ChatUserProfileComponent
```

Currently, you are using the wrong template reference so you are getting this undefined error because there is no template with reference **'app-modal'**.

Comment: Hi thank you for your tip it did not solve my problem but I understand better now how the templates are used.